# Why GPUs comes more into play than CPUS when it comes to dealing with Deep Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning, cpu

In almost most of the cases, I come across about GPUs while dealing with any execution part in Deep Learning.

Comment: I'm torn between upvoting this question out of curiosity and downvoting it because of how little research/info it contains. Is the question constructive? I don't know.

Comment: I decided for downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with GPU architecture versus CPU. It turns out gaming requires a lot of matrix multiplications, hence the GPU architecture was optimized for these types of operations, specifically they are optimized for high rate floating-point arithmetic. More on this [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/gpumatrixmult/gpumatrixmult.pdf)

It so happens that neural networks are mostly matrix multiplications.

For example:

[image: simple neural net with 1 hidden layer]

Is the mathematical formulation of a simple neural network with one hidden layer. W_h is a matrix of weights that multiplies your input x, to which we add a bias b_h. The linear equation W_hx + b_h can be compacted to a single matrix multiplication. The sigma is a nonlinear activation like sigmoid. The outer sigmoid is again a matrix multiplication. Hence GPUs

Comment: Matrix Multiplication. Thanks @vega

Comment: @S.P If you feel this answered your question, please check it as answered :)